# Match everything in string except in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match anything except between ' quotes '. If possible between `'` `"` `` ` `` quotes (I know I can use `` ['"`] ``).

Here is my regex pattern which just gets all text in between `'` `"` `` ` ``.

```
^((?!\'.*\').*)$
```

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/9PJ6aS/1/)

**Note:** I am talking about JavaScript Regex, therefor, I don't need PHP or Python regex patterns.

```js
let string = 'lorem \'ipsum\' dolor'
let match = string.match(/^((?!\'.*\').*)$/)
console.log('[===Real output===]')
console.log(match[1])
console.log('[===Expected output===]')
console.log('lorem  dolor')
```

Comment: Try `.replace(/\s*((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')/g, '$1').trim()`

Comment: It worked, thanks. But try making it as answer so i can mark it as solution

Comment: Do you really need to support escaped quotes? Just to make sure the solution is not too complex that it needs be.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't see anything here to "support escaped quotes". Every `\'` in this question represents a literal `'`. (And, yes, the backslashes in this regex are unnecessary, since `'` isn't a special character and `\'` isn't an escape sequence.)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to remove all quoted items in a string, not match all _non-quoted_ items. Maybe change your title ?

Comment: @DavidKnipe 95% of questions related to matching something inside quotes is about matching string literals, and they feaure escape sequences. So, it was my first thought, especially taking into account the string used for the code demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To separate the quotes by type so they do not get mixed (ex. `"words'`), `\B`: Non-word Boundary meta sequence was wrapped around each **QUOTE**`.+?`**QUOTE** and then each of those expressions separated by `|`: OR.

```
/(\B(".+?")\B|\B('.+?')\B|\B(`.+?`)\B)/g;
```

Alternatively, **QUOTE**`.*?`**QUOTE** could be used if you expect empty quotes as well.

---

### [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/Sv5Yjb/1)

### Demo

```js
var rgx = /(\B(".+?")\B|\B('.+?')\B|\B(`.+?`)\B)/g;

var str = `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", consectetur adipisicing elit, "'sed do eiusmod tempor,'" incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, \`quis nostrud\` exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \`Duis aute irure dolor\` in "reprehenderit in voluptate" velit esse cillum 'dolore eu fugiat nulla' pariatur. `;

var sub = ``;

var res = str.replace(rgx, sub);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the **" ' `** and then use that match to find the other one, after matching any characters besides the one of the **" ' `** that we just found

```javascript
string.replace(/(['"`])(?:(?!\1)[\s\S])+\1/g, '')
```

If you want it to match no characters in between marks, as well, then:

```javascript
string.replace(/(['"`]).*?\1/g, '')
```

Comment: `[^\1]` matches any char but the `\x01` char. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mvxN3P/1).

Comment: Oops, what's the correct format for a matched group?

Comment: It can be `(?:(?!\1)[\s\S])*`

Comment: Okay, fixed both, realized I didn't need to match anything for the second one

Comment: Yeah, although `.replace(/(['"\`])[^]*?\1/g, '')` is better. Though none support escape sequences.